# Accessing out parameter of mysql stored procedure in python/django

Tags: python

I am trying to execute a procedure that insert/update table data. based on that it return value in OUT variable. I want to access that out variable value.

Python code:

```
out = None
args = [int(roll_id), roll_name, profile.id, setting_str, out]
result = cursor.callproc('pro_insert_roll_setting', args)
cursor.execute('select @output_mes')
```

And Procedure is

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `pro_insert_roll_setting`(

    IN     in_id                   INTEGER ,
    IN     in_name                  VARCHAR(1024),
    IN     in_admin_id              INT ,
    IN    in_setting_type           VARCHAR(1024),
    OUT output_mes                  INTEGER
     )
```

after `print(result, cursor.fetchall())`, I get `([None, u'test3', 3897L, u'2#0,3#0,4#1', None], ())`.
How to access that `output_mes` value?

Comment: Why not use the django orm?

Comment: @WaketZheng the logic is already written in procedures and for this logic multiple tables are involved, that's why we are not using orm for this to reduce db hit like ORM->dB->ORM

Comment: You'd better show the code  `models.py`